# Date Range Query not working mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have UesrFeedback document as describe below with date and I wanted to find out all documents between start and end dates. I am not getting correct result I get result that is out of range from start and end dates.

Here is document:

```
class UserFeedbackImpl{
    private String userId;
    @Indexed
    private String resourceId;
    @Indexed
    private String resoruceType;
    private String rating;
    private String comments;
    private Date creationTimeStamp = new Date();
}
```

MongoDB query:

```
public List<UserFeedback> findUserFeedback(Date Start, Date end){
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("creationTimeStamp").gte(Start).andOperator(Criteria.where("creationTimeStamp").lte(end)));
    List<UserFeedbackImpl> pref = getTemplate().find(query,UserFeedbackImpl.class);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a Mongo Cookbook article on this topic: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Answer (score 3):

I believe the andOperator takes in a list of Criteria as its parameters, so you'd want

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.andOperator( Criteria.where("creationTimeStamp").gte(Start), Criteria.where("creationTimeStamp").lte(end) ));
```

This is according to the spring documentation here: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.0.0.M5/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#andOperator(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...)